# Find all nodes that have an attribute that matches a certain value with scala

Tags: xml, scala, parsing

I saw the following example on [Nabble](http://www.nabble.com/Matching-XML-elements-with-a-specific-value-for-an-attribute-td23375285.html), where the goal was to return all nodes that contain an attribute with an id of X that contains a value Y:

```
//find all nodes with an attribute "class" that contains the value "test"
val xml = XML.loadString( """<div>
<span class="test">hello</span>
<div class="test"><p>hello</p></div>
</div>""" )

def attributeEquals(name: String, value: String)(node: Node) = 
{ 
    node.attribute(name).filter(_==value).isDefined
}

val testResults = (xml \\ "_").filter(attributeEquals("class","test")) 
//prints: ArrayBuffer(
//<span class="test">hello</span>, 
//<div class="test"><p>hello</p></div>
//) 
println("testResults: " + testResults )
```

As an extension to this how would one do the following: Find all nodes that contain any attribute that contains a value of Y:

```
//find all nodes with any attribute that contains the value "test"
val xml = XML.loadString( """<div>
 <span class="test">hello</span>
 <div id="test"><p>hello</p></div>
 <random any="test"/></div>""" )
 //should return: ArrayBuffer(
 //<span class="test">hello</span>, 
 //<div id="test"><p>hello</p></div>, 
 //<random any="test"/> )
```

I was thinking I could use a _ like so:

```
val testResults = (xml \\ "_").filter(attributeEquals("_","test"))
```

But it doesn't work. I know I can use pattern matching, but just wanted to see if I could do some magic with the filtering.

Cheers - Ed

Comment: I found Xpath language is simpler https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.xpath and is compile time safe in Scala

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, XML are literals in Scala, so:

```
val xml = <div><span class="test">hello</span><div class="test"><p>hello</p></div></div>
```

Now, as to the problem:

```
def attributeValueEquals(value: String)(node: Node) = {
     node.attributes.exists(_.value.text == value)
}
```

In fact, I'd have used "`exists`" instead of "`filter`" and "`defined`" for the original problem as well.

Finally, I personally prefer operator style syntax, particularly when you have a ready function, instead of an anonymous one, to pass to "`filter`":

```
val testResults = xml \\ "_" filter attributeValueEquals("test")
```

The original mixes operator style for "`\\`" and dot style for "`filter`", which ends up quite ugly.

Comment: if you are using scala 2.9.1, please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819485/in-regards-of-finding-all-nodes-that-have-an-attribute-that-matches-a-certain-va (this selected answer returns a NodeSeq() on 2.9.1

Answer (score 3):

Code snippet in the question doesn't working with Scala 2.8 - due to this comparasion

```
(_ == value)
```

Needs to be replaced with `(_.text == value)` or `(_ == Text(value))` or change type of value from String to Text.

And in Daniel's answer `(_.value == value)` needs to be replaced with `(_.value.text == value)`.

Answer (score 3):

The previous solutions didn't work for me because they all look for *any* value that matches. If you want to look for a *particular* attribute with a value, here is my solution:

```
def getByAtt(e: Elem, att: String, value: String) = {
    def filterAtribute(node: Node, att: String, value: String) =  (node \ ("@" + att)).text == value   
    e \\ "_" filter { n=> filterAtribute(n, att, value)} 
}
```

And then

```
getByAtt(xml, "class", "test")
```

This will differentiate between `class="test"` and `"notclass="test"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Scala, I propose you this solution, but I'm not sure this is the best one:

```
def attributeValueEquals(value: String)(node: Node) = {
  node.attributes.foldLeft(false)((a : Boolean, x : MetaData) => a | (x.value == value))
}

val testResults = (xml \\ "_").filter(attributeValueEquals("test")) 
println("testResults: " + testResults )

// prints: testResults: ArrayBuffer(<span class="test">hello</span>, 
// <div id="test"><p>hello</p></div>, 
// <random any="test"></random>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nodeHasValue(node:Node,value:String) = node.attributes.value != null && node.attributes.value.contains(value)

(x \\ "_").filter( nodeHasValue(_,"test"))
```

Comment: I would suggest maxme's answer for the currying, but my answer for the use of 'contains' rather than a fold. Combine them!

Comment: Well, Daniel's answer beats both. Kudos.